# Transforming pass-by reference into pass-by return

Tags: c++, function, c++11, refactoring, pass-by-reference

I have the following function:

```
void read_int(std::vector<int> &myVector)
```

Which allows me to fill `myVector` through it reference. It is used like this:

```
std::vector<int> myVector;
read_int(myVector);
```

I want to refactor a bit the code (keeping the original function) to in the end have this:

```
auto myVector = read_int();   // auto is std::vector<int>
```

What would be the best intermediate function to achieve this?

---

It seems to me that the following straight-forward answer is suboptimal:

```
std::vector<int> read_int() {
    std::vector<int> myVector_temp;
    read_int(myVector_temp);
    return myVector_temp;
}
```

Comment: And why do you think this is suboptimal?

Comment: Wouldn't the new function create an intermediate `vector<int>` which will then be copied in the declaration?

Comment: What you have looks far superior to your original version. If you are worried about performance, read up on [return value optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization).

Comment: This is fine, though it would probably be better to not wrap the function and actually refactor. The std::vector<int> will be elided when it can and moved when it can't, so returning a vector by value is pretty much the right way to go.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Thanks, didn't know about return value optimization!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obvious answer is correct, and basically optimal.

```
void do_stufF(std::vector<int>& on_this);    // (1)
std::vector<int> do_stuff_better() {         // (2)
    std::vector<int> myVector_temp;          // (3)
    do_stuff(myVector_temp);                 // (4)
    return myVector_temp;                    // (5)
}
```

At **(3)** we create a named return value in automatic storage (on the stack).

At **(5)** we only ever return the named return value from the function, and we never return anything else but that named return value anywhere else in the function.

Because of **(3)** and **(5)**, the compiler is allowed to (and most likely will) elide the existence of the `myVector_temp` object.  It will directly construct the return value of the function, and *call it* `myVector_temp`.  It still needs there to be an existing move or copy constructor, but it does not call it.

On the other end, when calling `do_stuff_better`, some compilers can also elide the assignment at call:

```
std::vector<int> bob = do_stuff_better();     // (6)
```

The compiler is allowed to effectively pass a "pointer to bob" and tell `do_stuff_better()` to construct its return value in `bob`'s location, eliding this copy construction as well (well, it can arrange how the call occurs such that the location that `do_stuff_better()` is asked to construct its return value in is the same as the location of `bob`).

And in C++11, even if the requirements for both elisions are not met, or the compiler chooses not to use them, in both cases a `move` must be done instead of a `copy`.

At line **(5)** we are returning a locally declared automatic storage duration variable in a plain and simple `return` statement.  This makes the return an implicit `move` if not elided.

At line **(6)**, the function returns an unnamed object, which is an rvalue.  When `bob` is constructed from it, it `move`-constructs.

`move`ing a `std::vector` consists of copying the value of ~3 pointers, and then zeroing the source, regardless of how big the `vector` is.  No elements need be copied or moved.

Both of the above elisions, where we remove the named local variable within `do_stuff_better()`, and we remove the `return` value of `do_stuff_better()` and instead directly construct `bob`, are somewhat fragile.  Learning the rules under which your compiler is allowed to do those elisions, and also the situations where your compiler actually does the elisions, is worthwhile.

As an example of how it is fragile, if you had a branch where you did a `return std::vector<int>()` in your `do_stuff_better()` after checking an error state, the in-function elision would probably be blocked.

Even if elision is blocked or your compiler doesn't implement it for a case, the fact that the container is `move`'d means that the run time costs are going to be minimal.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you have to read more about [move semantics](http://www.google.pl/search?client=opera&q=C%2B%2B11+move+semantics) (link to Google query, there are a lot of papers on this - just choose one).

In short, in C++ all STL containers are written in such way, that returning them from function will cause their contents to be moved from the returned value (so called right-hand reference) to the variable you are assigning it to. In effect you'll only copy a few fields of the std::vector instead of its data. That's a lot faster than copying its contents.

Comment: This will only happen if the copy is not elided. And copy elision works in C++03 too :)

Comment: @juanchopanza Sure, but the question is tagged C++11 anyway. Despite that, it's indeed a fact worth noticing.